# ImportError: Numpy OpenBLAS flavour is needed for this scipy build

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm

I use python 2.7 on PyCharm and I try to make a surface from a file points and i read that the way from do this is through libraries matplotlib, mpl_toolkits. But when i run the code that i copy from example's web i have this error:

C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/rublloal/PycharmProjects/untitled3/matplotlib1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rublloal/PycharmProjects/untitled3/matplotlib1.py", line 10, in 
    from scipy.misc import imread                   # Cargo imread de scipy.misc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy__init__.py", line 122, in 
    raise ImportError("Numpy OpenBLAS flavour is needed for this scipy build.")
ImportError: Numpy OpenBLAS flavour is needed for this scipy build.

thanks

Comment: How did you install numpy, scipy and matplotlib?

Comment: I installed three libraries from Pycharm with option "import name_of_library"
But for matplotlib and scipy i need install binding:
matplotlib-1.5.1-cp27-none-win32.whl
scipy-0.16.0-cp27-none-win32.whl
from cmd:
python -m pip install name_of_binding

Comment: I use version 5.0.3 of PyCharm and is like says at this link on the right from text "upgrade a package" the example with import celery

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

I use python 2.7 on PyCharm and I downgrade the scipy 0.18 to 0.16 and I had the same problem as you, but I reinstall numpy - (numpy-1.10.0b1-cp27-none-win32.whl) by pip.

You can find the wheel here: https://pypi.anaconda.org/carlkl/simple/numpy/ 
and problem disappear. 
Maybe I answered to late, but I hope it will help someone else :)